# Eaccess Permission error in Node.js Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, backend, fedora

I have a Node.js application using Postgres and redis all inside docker-compose.

It runs perfectly when the volume is not specified in app container. I'm using fedora but when I try on Garuda Linux, there is no such error.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN chown -R node:node /app

USER node

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Error:

```
app         | Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/package.json'
app         |     at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
app         |     at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
app         |     at onUnexpectedError (/opt/yarn-v1.22.19/lib/cli.js:88615:106)
app         |     at /opt/yarn-v1.22.19/lib/cli.js:88734:9
```

Comment: Does the issue only happen when you map a volume on to `/app`?

Comment: Haven't tried to mount on any other path.

Comment: But there's no volume mapping in your docker-compose file, so it's a little hard to guess what you're doing

Comment: volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules

this is the mapping i'm performing

Comment: Your issue is that the node user in the container (UID 1000, GID 1000) doesn't have access to the files on your host. The easy fix is to run the container as root.

Comment: I run them as root user only via sudo docker-compose up --build

Comment: It runs as the node user because you have `USER node` in your Dockerfile

Comment: Even after removing `USER node`, the same issue is there

Comment: Did you re-build the image?

Comment: Yes I did but still the same

Comment: The same application works in Garuda Linux but not in Fedora and that's the thing bothering me here

Comment: You don't need the `volumes:` to overwrite the code in the `app` container; it's already build into the image.  If you delete that `volumes:` block do things work better?

Comment: Yes but then hot reload doesn't work. Everytime I make a change in any js file, I have to rebuild.

Comment: Could this be a `selinux` issue?  What is the output of `getenforce`?